# Proving inequalities using Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus

I was given the this inequality : $x>\sin x> x-\frac{x^3}{6}$ for $x>0$

What I want to know is the standard approach for solving this kind of questions?can anyone give me the guideline?

thank you!

Comment: Are you solving for $x$ or are you trying to show that this inequality holds? Note that this inequality can be seen from taylors expansion as well

Comment: @illysial the ques asks to show using Mean value theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that both inequalities attain equality at $x=0$.

Hint: Consider the function $f(x):= x- \sin x$. If $x>0$, then the mean value theorem states that there exists $c$ such that $0 \le c \le x$ and $f'(c)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\frac{f(x)}{x}$. See if you can conclude that $f(x)>0$.

> Note that $f'(c)\ge 0$ for all $c \ge 0$.

Comment: thanks but now I am thinking of how to show the second inequality

Comment: @UnusualSkill Do the same thing, but multiple times (see OC-Sansoo's answer)

Comment: oic thanks so much both of you!

Comment: If using MVT, without any other theorem or corollaries from MVT, we can not prove that strict inequality, that is, $x>\sin(x), \forall x>0.$ Indeed, we can prove these inequalities by convex argument, or by definite integral argument.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(x)=\sin x$ is continuous on $[0,x]$ and differentiable on $(0,x)$ so the mean value theorem is satisfied. Then there exists $c \in (0,1)$ so that
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}&=f'(x) \\
\frac{\sin x}{x}&=\cos c\\
\sin x&=x\cos c.
\end{align*}
The result follows due to $-1 \leq\cos x\leq 1$.

Can you do the other case?

Answer (score 0):

For the second inequality: $\sin x - x + \dfrac{x^3}{6} > 0 \iff \cos x - 1 + \dfrac{x^2}{2} > 0 \iff -\sin x + x > 0 \iff -\cos x + 1 > 0$ which is clear. Same trick for the first one.

Comment: I don understand why cos x -1 +x^2/2 is greater than 0?

Comment: g'(x)=cos x -1 +0.5x^2 is positive for all x>0?I cant see it

Answer (score 0):

To prove the  giving strict equalities, we need the following theorem

**Theorem (Strict Monotonicity)**  $\quad $ Let $I$ be a nonempty interval (open, or closed, or half-open, and bounded, or unbounded) in the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}.$  Assume function $f: I\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies that $f\in C(I)$ and $f$ is differentiable in $\text{int}(I),$ where $\text{int}(I)$ is the interior of $I.$ Then we have the following:
$\quad f$ is strictly increasing on $I,$ if and only if:

$(\alpha)$ $f'(x)\geq 0, \forall x\in \text{int}(I);$

$(\beta) $ the critical set  of $f,$ that is, $$\text{CS}(f):=\{x\in I\mid
 f'(x)=0\},$$ 
does not contain any *non-degenerate* interval of $\mathbb{R}.$

Here an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ is *non-degenerate* if and only if its length is positive.

**Proof of the inequalities**. let $I=[0,+\infty)$ and consider the two functions 
\begin{gather*}
f: x\in I\mapsto x-\sin(x),\\
g: x\in I\mapsto \sin(x)-x+\frac{x^3}{6}.
\end{gather*} 
Then we see that $f, g'\in C(I)$ and furthermore, $f, g'$ are differentiable in $\text{int}(I).$  Differentiate $f$ and $g,$ we get
\begin{gather*}
f'(x)=1-\cos(x)\geq 0, \qquad \forall x\in\text{int}(I),\\
g'(x)=\cos(x)-1+\frac{x^2}{2},\qquad \forall x\in \text{int}(I),\\
g''(x)=x-\sin(x),\qquad \forall x\in \text{int}(I).
\end{gather*}
Observe that 
\begin{gather*}
f'(x)=0, \forall x\in\text{int}(I)\iff \cos(x)=1\iff x=2n\pi, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}
\end{gather*}
which shows that $\text{CS}(f)$ dose not contain any non-degenerate interval. Thus, by the Theorem above, we conclude that $f$ is increasing strictly on $I,$ which implies that, for every $x>0,$ we have $f(x)>f(0)=0,$ and so, we get
\begin{gather*}
x-\sin(x)>0, \text{ or  equivalently,} \sin(x)<x, \qquad \forall x>0.
\end{gather*} 
Now consider $g.$ We see that, by what we have just proved, $g''(x)>g''(0)=0, \forall x\in\text{int}(I).$ By Theorem above, we see that $g'(x)$ is increasing strictly on $I,$ as a result, we have $g'(x)>g'(0)=0, \forall x>0.$ And then, using Theorem above to $g,$ we conclude that $g$ is also increasing on $I,$ and so 
\begin{gather*}
g(x)>g(0)=0,\qquad \forall x>0,
\end{gather*} 
which is equivalent to 
\begin{gather*}
\sin(x)>x-\frac{x^3}{3!},\qquad \forall x>0.
\end{gather*}